# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jsonarray

intente ser lo mas claro con el titulo pero cuesta si no se sabe bien el problema.

Estoy intentando traer un total de 40 registros de una base de datos con dos campos, ID_bank y name (número nominal y nombre de dicho banco).

La consulta es simplemente un SELECT * FROM bank, tanto en php como en el lado del controller, no me figura un error, pero a la hora de llenar un array con los datos de la consulta, me da vacio.

La conexion a la base de datos esta bien, la consulta dificilmente este mal, creo que hay algo entre el array y los resultados. Antes de publicar hice una ultima prueba y me arrojo el error en la linea del $json[]= array(....);. Dejo el codigo php y luego en ajax.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
    include("../system/conexion.php");
    

   
    $information = "SELECT * FROM bank";
    $ejecucion=mysqli_query($conexion, $information);
    $response=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion);
 
    $json = array();

    while($response=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion)){
         $json[]= array('id_bank' => $response['id_bank'], 'name' => $response['name']);
    }

    
    $jsonstring= json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
    

    mysqli_close($conexion);
}else{
    echo "No esta autorizado para este sitio";
}
```

?>

```
function banks(){
    //esto es una funcion en ajax. el get_data es otra funcion, un simple $.ajax
    get_data('../../model/bank/get_banks.php').then(response =>{
        console.log(response);
        let data = JSON.parse(response); 
        console.log(data); //es redundante pero queria asegurarme de poder ver el response que siempre vino vacio
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Me parece muy raro el error ya que en mi vida traje mas de 40 registros con muchas mas columnas, pero me preocupa ya que este sistema traera cientos de filas en varios modulos y esta es la primera vez que hago una prueba con mas de 10 registros. Cualquier ayuda y explicación del problema se agradece. Ya que la tabla no es compleja, les dejo el codigo con sus datos para la creacion de la misma tabla.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bank` (
  `id_bank` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_bank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Volcando datos para la tabla cripto_bd.bank: ~40 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bank` DISABLE KEYS */;
REPLACE INTO `bank` (`id_bank`, `name`) VALUES
    ('00007', 'BANCO DE GALICIA Y BUENOS AIRES S.A.U.'),
    ('00011', 'BANCO DE LA NACION ARGENTINA'),
    ('00014', 'BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE BUENOS AIRES'),
    ('00015', ' INDUSTRIAL AND COMMERCIAL BANK OF CHINA'),
    ('00016', 'CITIBANK N.A.'),
    ('00017', 'BANCO BBVA ARGENTINA S.A.'),
    ('00020', 'BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE CORDOBA S.A.'),
    ('00027', 'BANCO SUPERVIELLE S.A.'),
    ('00029', 'BANCO DE LA CIUDAD DE BUENOS AIRES'),
    ('00034', 'BANCO PATAGONIA S.A.'),
    ('00044', 'BANCO HIPOTECARIO S.A.'),
    ('00045', 'BANCO DE SAN JUAN S.A.'),
    ('00065', 'BANCO MUNICIPAL DE ROSARIO'),
    ('00072', 'BANCO SANTANDER RIO S.A.'),
    ('00083', 'BANCO DEL CHUBUT S.A.'),
    ('00086', 'BANCO DE SANTA CRUZ S.A.'),
    ('00093', 'BANCO DE LA PAMPA SOCIEDAD DE ECONOMÍA M'),
    ('00094', 'BANCO DE CORRIENTES S.A.'),
    ('00097', 'BANCO PROVINCIA DEL NEUQUÉN SOCIEDAD ANÓ'),
    ('00143', 'BRUBANK S.A.U.'),
    ('00147', 'BANCO INTERFINANZAS S.A.'),
    ('00150', 'HSBC BANK ARGENTINA S.A.'),
    ('00165', 'JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NATIONAL ASSOCIATIO'),
    ('00191', 'BANCO CREDICOOP COOPERATIVO LIMITADO'),
    ('00198', 'BANCO DE VALORES S.A.'),
    ('00247', 'BANCO ROELA S.A.'),
    ('00254', 'BANCO MARIVA S.A.'),
    ('00259', 'BANCO ITAU ARGENTINA S.A.'),
    ('00262', 'BANK OF AMERICA, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION'),
    ('00266', 'BNP PARIBAS'),
    ('00268', 'BANCO PROVINCIA DE TIERRA DEL FUEGO'),
    ('00269', ' BANCO DE LA REPUBLICA ORIENTAL DEL URUGUAY'),
    ('00277', 'BANCO SAENZ S.A.'),
    ('00281', 'BANCO MERIDIAN S.A.'),
    ('00285', 'BANCO MACRO S.A.'),
    ('00299', 'BANCO COMAFI SOCIEDAD anonima'),
    ('00300', 'BANCO DE INVERSION Y COMERCIO EXTERIOR S'),
    ('00301', 'BANCO PIANO S.A.'),
    ('00305', 'BANCO JULIO SOCIEDAD ANONIMA'),
    ('00448', 'BANCO DINO S.A.');
```

Comment: Entras a un ciclo infinito con `while($response)`, hasta que se acaba la memoria.

Comment: @Sal si, lo cambie a while($response=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion)){} aun asi, sigue devolviendome un json vacio en el controller

Answer (score 1):

Pude encontrar la repuesta. probe con un var_dump($json) (para concer el conetenido del $json que enviaba al controller) y noté que las "ñ" las marcaba con error, asi que antes de guardarlas en el arreglo, le coloque un utf8_encode al nombre del registro.

```
while($response=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucion)){
        $bank_name = utf8_encode($response['name']);
        $json[]= array('id_bank' => $response['id_bank'], 'name' => $bank_name);
    }
```